# Adding a foreign key to existing table

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl, ora-01735

I have been trying to add these keys to my table but I get an error

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

My code:

```
ALTER TABLE Room
ADD FOREIGN KEY (RoomType_ID) REFERENCES RoomType(RoomType_ID), 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Reservation_ID) REFERENCES Reservation(Reservation_ID), 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Gust_ID) REFERENCES Gust(Gust_ID);
```

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE Gust ( Gust_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, First_Name VARCHAR(50), Last_Name VARCHAR(50), Email VARCHAR(20), phone_number INT(10), Address VARCHAR(30) )

CREATE TABLE Reservation ( Reservation_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Start_Date Date, End_Date Date )

CREATE TABLE Room ( Room_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Price INT )

CREATE TABLE RoomType ( RoomType_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Class VARCHAR(10), ExtraPrice INT )
```

Comment: It looks like your syntax is wrong, you need to include `ADD CONSTRAINT` . See here at the bottom: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ALTER` statement for a multiple `FOREIGN KEYS` does not work.

Each `CONSTRAINT` should be added individually :

```
CREATE TABLE Gust ( Gust_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, First_Name VARCHAR(50), Last_Name VARCHAR(50), Email VARCHAR(20), phone_number INT, Address VARCHAR(30) );
CREATE TABLE Reservation ( Reservation_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Start_Date Date, End_Date Date );
CREATE TABLE RoomType ( RoomType_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Class VARCHAR(10), ExtraPrice INT );

CREATE TABLE Room(Room_ID int PRIMARY KEY, Price INT, Reservation_ID int,Gust_ID int );

ALTER TABLE Room ADD FOREIGN KEY (Room_ID) REFERENCES RoomType(RoomType_ID);

ALTER TABLE Room ADD FOREIGN KEY (Reservation_ID) REFERENCES Reservation(Reservation_ID); 
-- the table Room is assumed to have a column Reservation_ID 

ALTER TABLE Room ADD FOREIGN KEY (Gust_ID) REFERENCES Gust(Gust_ID);
    -- the table Room is assumed to have a column Gust_ID
```

If System-generated constraint name not to be wanted, then using these ;

```
ALTER TABLE Room ADD CONSTRAINT fk_RoomType_ID FOREIGN KEY (Room_ID) 
                                               REFERENCES RoomType(RoomType_ID);

ALTER TABLE Room ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Reservation_ID FOREIGN KEY (Reservation_ID) 
                                                REFERENCES Reservation(Reservation_ID); 

ALTER TABLE Room ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Gust_ID FOREIGN KEY (Gust_ID) 
                                           REFERENCES Gust(Gust_ID);
```

may be preferred.

P.S. :

- Do Not Use `NOT NULL` with `PRIMARY KEY`, `PRIMARY KEY` already
  includes `NOT NULL`.
- The length can not be defined for an `INT` column.

Comment: I get this error "ORA-00904: "ROOMTYPE_ID": invalid identifier"

Comment: @MissSHOOSH Assuming you have a column named `ROOMTYPE_ID` in `Room` table, i used that column.

Comment: do i have to Alter the table to add columns first? then adding the fk?

Comment: @MissSHOOSH you should add columns first, of course.

Comment: Thank you!! that did it .. I totally forgot that I have to add the columns first .. Again Thank you..

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I have been banging my head for useless reasons for a while now.