# Adding multiple foreign keys using alter in Oracle SQL Live

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My question is very simple I'm just trying to add foreign keys to an already existing table.

I want to add all foreign keys for each table in one statement I'm trying to do

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER
  ADD 
     FOREIGN KEY (Shipping_Com_ID) REFERENCES Shipping_Com(Shipping_Com_ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (Product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCT_FILE(Product_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (Payment_id) REFERENCES Payment(Payment_id);
```

but that's not working - I get this error:

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of tool you using? In TOAD I suppose, you need to execute it as a script (press F5) rather that running it as a statement.

Also i think that is your solution [Adding a foreign key to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886532/adding-a-foreign-key-to-existing-table)

Answer (score 0):

Invalid syntax. Not like you did it:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER
  2    ADD
  3       FOREIGN KEY (Shipping_Com_ID) REFERENCES Shipping_Com(Shipping_Com_ID),
  4       FOREIGN KEY (Product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCT_FILE(Product_id),
  5       FOREIGN KEY (Payment_id) REFERENCES Payment(Payment_id);
     FOREIGN KEY (Shipping_Com_ID) REFERENCES Shipping_Com(Shipping_Com_ID),
                                                                           *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

Foreign keys should be enclosed into parenthesis (lines #3 and 7):

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER
  2    ADD
  3    (
  4       FOREIGN KEY (Shipping_Com_ID) REFERENCES Shipping_Com(Shipping_Com_ID),
  5       FOREIGN KEY (Product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCT_FILE(Product_id),
  6       FOREIGN KEY (Payment_id) REFERENCES Payment(Payment_id)
  7    );

Table altered.

SQL>
```